# amzon s3 boto, grant a new group IAM access, 403 error

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, amazon-iam

I am using this code, which is very simple but it doesn't work. any ideas why? You should be able to run it if you have the credentials.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
import boto
import json

iam = boto.connect_iam(main_aws_id,main_aws_key)
iam.create_group('test_admin')

create_admin_policy = {"Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Action":"*", "Resource":"*"}]}
admin_policy=json.dumps(create_admin_policy)

iam.put_group_policy('test_admin', 'AdminPolicy', admin_policy)

iam.create_user('harry')

iam.add_user_to_group('test_admin', 'harry')

key_response=iam.create_access_key('harry')

a=json.dumps(key_response).split(',')   #my way of getting user's id and key
user_AWS_ID=a[4][19:-3]
user_AWS_KEY=a[3][23:-3]

#needs a bit of time for the key to activates

user_conn=S3Connection(user_AWS_ID,user_AWS_KEY)
user_conn.create_bucket('harry_bucket')   #returns: 403 Forbidden. the request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your code that tries to extract the `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` from the `create_access_key` method.  Your code ends up truncating two characters from the `secret_access_key`.  A better way to get the values would be to do this:

```
user_conn=boto.connect_s3(key_response.access_key_id, key_response.secret_access_key)
user_conn.create_bucket('<bucket_name>')
```

There is no need to convert the `key_response` to a JSON string since the IAM calls return a special Python dictionary that allows you to access any embedded key by accessing it as an attribute.  You could also use normal dictionary access like this:

```
key_response['create_access_key_response']['create_access_key_result']['access_key']['access_key_id']
```

But as you can see, this is rather clumsy.

Comment: I can't believe that mistake. Thanks for helping.